# Use JavaScript to disable all buttons on a page until a refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a page that will cause an error if a user tries to click too many buttons at one time (for the impatient user) and therefore need to DISable any button (all defined by a JS onclick function) on the page until it is refreshed (with new data sent via the server using Java.) What is the best method to do this, and is there a way to do it with jQuery?

Comment: `.one()` could help you; simply add it again when you're ready :)

Comment: You can use jQuery Block ui to lock the entire UI (not only buttons) while you are waiting the end of the ajax call. Can this be good? Are you calling server side processing via ajax?

Comment: We cannot use AJAX since the server call would be too late. Calling the server at all will trigger the error. I'm trying to use jQuery Block UI to do this, but not having much success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single best solution is to use the BlockUI plugin for jQuery. It accomplished everything I needed and more. http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 1):

How about simply calling this when you want to disable the buttons:

```
jQuery('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

That will disable all inputs of type button on the page.  Of course, as soon as you reload/replace the page contents, the new buttons will not be disabled.  You can also just disable all inputs if that's easier.

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/xDMux/

Comment: See my comment, below. I'm unable to target "input" elements, since the buttons are not standard form buttons.

Comment: OK, so target whatever the "Buttons" have in common.  If they all have a class of btnimg, then use jQuery('.btnimg')

Answer (score 1):

You would have to find all types of buttons using something like this..

```
$('input[type="submit"], button')
```

and loop through the returned array and do `.attr('disabled','disabled');` on the item in each iteration.

Comment: The problem with this is the code is using non-standard buttons (i.e. they are not input elements.) A typical button on the page would be: <img src="images/btn/createUser.gif" width="70" height="22"class="btnimg"  onClick="createUser()">

Comment: that works -- and, even using jQuery Block UI works, but now I have a broader problem! Do I start a new question, or continue to use this thread to see if I can get any answers?

Comment: Well if it has fixed the disabling of the buttons, maybe start a new thread.

Comment: Thank you, my issue is resolved. I now need to figure out the other problems it created. :)